# Dynamic agent in pedestrian library is not getting connected using Distance Based Network in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I am trying to make dynamic model where in the agents(pedestrians) move in an environment and must be connected if the condition is distance based  is satisfied.

I took reference from online resources,however I could only get a connected agent when the agents are static and not when agents are moving like in a pedestrian.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Avron

Comment: Using a distance-based network in the parent agent's properties *only* applies that network at model startup (and not for any dynamically-added agents). You need to write code to dynamically connect/disconnect at relevant time intervals if you need to dynamically maintain a 'distance-based network'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a conditional event (i don't know how) then i wouldn't trust it so much...

But maybe you can use this rather inefficient technique, that can be made more efficient depending on what kind of model you have: (this should run in a cyclic event inside each one of your pedestrian agents)

```
for(Pedestrian p : main.pedestrians){
    if(!p.equals(this)){
        if(p.distanceTo(this)<100){//assuming 100 is the distance you want
            connections.connectTo(p);
        }else{
            connections.disconnectFrom(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I  am making a environment with relations to social distancing in an environement. However, I am new to anylogic therefore I would like to know if the above code should be initiated in the Startup section of the agent(pedestrian) or on  the step section? And is the paramater put in the Main Agent-Network Type-Distance no longer required when I use the code? Regards,Avron